# How to apply VBA countifs to Excel matrix with variable criteria

Tags: excel, vba, variables, sumifs

I have a fairly simply code to give me a sumifs from an external table. I now need to apply this code to a matrix of variables that will result in different totals depending on the cell.

A great example of this is if I was writing a sumifs in excel, with years across the columns and months down the rows, it would look something like this.
=sumifs("sum range",$A2,"month criteria range",B$2,"year criteria range")

How can I make my VBA code below act like this formula, having unlocked my rows and columns so the criteria is variable? Here's what I'm working with.

```
Sub SumifsOR()
    Dim ary As Variant
    Dim x As Long
    Dim year As Variant
    Dim month As Variant
    Dim titlerange As Long
    titlerange = Range("'Back End Lookups and Valiations'!L10000").End(xlUp).row
    ary = Range("'Back End Lookups and Valiations'!L2:L" & titlerange).Value
    year = Range("G118")
    month = Range("B119")
    
    For Each n In ary
       x = x + WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( _
            Range("'[Headcount Model - Raw Data.xlsx]BoM HC Report'!L:L"), n, _
            Range("'[Headcount Model - Raw Data.xlsx]BoM HC Report'!U:U"), year, _
            Range("'[Headcount Model - Raw Data.xlsx]BoM HC Report'!T:T"), month)
    Next
    
    Range("G119:I130") = x
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you have `Range("'[Headcount Model - Raw Data.xlsx]BoM HC Report'!L:L")` instead of `Worksheets("Headcount Model - Raw Data.xlsx").Worksheets("BoM HC Report").Range("L:L")`?  Also, why are you using `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs`, if you want the result to be a `WorksheetFunction.SumIfs`?  Finally, is "Back End Lookups and Valiations" a correct, a typo *here*, or a typo in your actual code?  (i.e. should it say "Vali**d**ations"?)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I'm not sure why exactly I used a different methodology for referencing the arrays. It works for me the way it's written so I don't see a need to change it. You're right, that I am including a countif instead of a sumif. This is an oversight on my part, I'll change it in the title. Lastly, yes, it's a typo for Validations. We can overlook that for now.